# Dificuldade em trabalhar com Thread no Spring Boot

Tags: thread, spring-boot

Observe como está meu controller

```
@PostMapping("/anexo")
    public DeferredResult<String> uploadAnexo(@RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile[] files){
        DeferredResult<String> resultado = new DeferredResult<>();

        // retorno assíncrono
        Thread thread = new Thread(new FotoStorageRunnable(files, resultado));
        thread.start();

        return resultado;
    }
```

E veja como está minha Thread

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class FotoStorageRunnable implements Runnable {

    private MultipartFile[] files;
    private DeferredResult<String> resultado;   


    public FotoStorageRunnable(MultipartFile[] files, DeferredResult<String> resultado) {
        this.files = files;
        this.resultado = resultado;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(">>> files: " + files[0].getSize());
        resultado.setResult("ok! esse é o resultado foto recebida");

    }

}
```

Essa mensagem deveria ter chegado no servidor;

```
System.out.println(">>> files: " + files[0].getSize());
```

E essa mensagens deveria ter chegado no cliente;

```
resultado.setResult("ok! esse é o resultado foto recebida");
```

Nenhuma dessas duas mensagens chegaram e ainda gerou essa mensagem de erro logo abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde será que está errado?

Answer (score 0):

O método uploadAnexo envia um parâmetro do tipo MultipartFile[] para o construtor da classe FotoStorageRunnable, aparentemente esse parâmetro está indo null, visto que a exception lançada é de que não existe nada na posição 0 do array.

Comment: Isso é a explicação da mensagem de erro, você teria uma sugestão de como contornar isso?

Comment: O erro que está gerando é 503, é um erro do servidor.

Comment: acabei de fazer um novo teste, eu tirei a linha de código que está na linha 19, ai a mensagem que está na linha 20 foi para o cliente, então o problema está na linha 19, teria que saber porque a variavel files está com problema.

Comment: estou seguindo essa linha de código
https://github.com/algaworks/curso-sistemas-web-com-spring-javascript-bootstrap/blob/master/14.4-melhorando-a-disponibilidade-da-aplicacao-retorno-assincrono/brewer/src/main/java/com/algaworks/brewer/controller/FotosController.java